# Continuously paste to a file in a loop without overwriting

Tags: linux, bash, paste

I would like to paste an output file from a loop side to side with each file generated from the loop without overwriting the file.

If it was just append it would be fine  with >> but struggling to find a way where I can keep adding to a file so columns side by side

```
cat a.txt >> final.txt
```

The files I have are in the format

```
File 1     file 2
123        108
176        193
123        145
```

I would like to paste these together

```
paste -d ' ' file1.txt file2.txt > final.txt
```

I would then like to continue adding to the file final with iterations through the loop

```
paste -d ' ' file3.txt final.txt >>final.txt
```

The output I would like then would have 3 columns- i.e file3.txt is not appended to the bottom thus increasing rows but added to the side like in a normal paste so the column no increases with each pase

```
123 108 125    
176 193 478
123 145 645
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I case it's not obvious, `paste -d ' ' file3.txt file1.txt file2.txt >final.txt` does what you want in a single step.

Comment: Yes but this loop runs 1000s of times so was hoping to avoid keeping file3.txt file1.txt and so on till the end... Currently I paste the XXthousand at the end using for f in *_${chr}_3.txt; do cat final_${chr}.txt | paste -d ' ' - $f >temp; cp temp final_${chr}.txt; done; but Im taking a lot of unnecessary space if i could just paste within the loop and keep adding to the file

Comment: That sounds horribly inefficient. Get the file names in the order you want them and `paste` them in one go. (You may have to break it up into multiple passes still if you have more files than you can fit into `ARG_MAX` before hitting "Argument list too long".)

Comment: how many files? what's the total size of these files? do all files have the same number of lines?

Answer (score 0):

In regular case you can append to a file like this:

```
cat a.txt &>> final.txt
```

But if you would like to get columns, you should use `paste`, e.g. to create .csv file:

```
paste -d , final.csv a.csv
```

.txt files are not the usual format for holding columns, so you should consider the .csv format.

Comment: Thank you but I dont think I was clear and have amended the question- cat will append a directly underneath the last row in final.txt - I dont want to increase the rows I want to directly paste the values side by side continuously so row length stays the same in the final.txt but the number of columns increases as a file is pasted through each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear why you'd want to do this instead of creating an output file once at the end of all processing but assuming it's useful:

```
seq 2 > file
for i in {1..3}; do
    seq 2 > tmp1 &&
    paste file tmp1 > tmp2 &&
    mv tmp2 file
    echo "-----"
    cat file
done
-----
1       1
2       2
-----
1       1       1
2       2       2
-----
1       1       1       1
2       2       2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

> truggling to find a way where I can keep adding to a file so columns side by side

You have to use a temporary file. (Or you could use `sponge` from `moreutils`.)

```
paste -d ' ' file3.txt final.txt >> final.txt.temp
mv final.txt.temp final.txt
```

> currently I paste the XXthousand at the end using for f in **${chr}*3.txt; do cat final*${chr}.txt | paste -d ' ' - $f >temp; cp temp final*${chr}.txt; done;

Just run it once.

```
paste -d ' ' *_${chr}_3.txt > final_${chr}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely simplest and most efficient solution is to simply run `paste` once, with all your input files as arguments.

Based on what you said in a comment, you seem to be looking simply for

```sh
paste -d ' ' *_"${chr}_3.txt" >"final_${chr}.txt"
```

If getting the files in a different order is important, try to organize the argument to `paste` first, perhaps by using an array. Here's with the files in reverse order:

```sh
files=( *_"${chr}_3.txt" )
reversed=( )
for((i=${#files[@]}; i>0; i--)); do
    reversed+=("${files[i]}")
done
paste -d ' ' "${reversed[@]}" >"final_${chr}.txt"
```

Arrays are a Bash-only feature (though also portable to `ksh` and more or less to Zsh); the earlier solution above is portable to any Bourne shell. This `for` loop syntax is also a Bash extension.

If you have a lot of files or your file names are very long, you may bump into "argument list too long" errors. The fix for that is to use `xargs`, though it can be a bit tricky to adapt to this scenario. Maybe also look at GNU `parallel` which has some features to simplify this sort of scenario. As an alternative, here's a simple recursive function which avoids any *explicit* temporary files.

```sh
ppaste () {
    case $# in
     1|2) paste -d ' ' "$@";;
     *) local first=$1
        shift
        paste -d ' ' "$first" <(ppaste "$@");;
    esac
}
```

The process substitution `<(...)` is again a Bash feature which isn't portable to POSIX `sh`.

Demo: https://ideone.com/FEwKYo